# Is it true: A real symmetric matrix is either positive definite or negative definite or indefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I got a real symmetric matrix that is neither positive definite or negative definite, so can I just say that this matrix is indefinite?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Is the zero matrix positive/negative definite or indefinite?

Comment: Thanks Santiago! Then how about this definition: a real symmetric matrix H is indefinite if x'Hx is positive for some nonzero real vector x and is negative for some nonzero real vector x. Is this definition correct?

Answer (score 2):

No. You have described all the real symmetric matrices with nonzero determinant. The others are usually called semidefinite, for example
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Next day: read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

It is enough to consider diagonal matrices here, because real symmetric matrices can be orthogonally diagonalized. There are three counts; first the matrix will be $n$ by $n.$ We call the number of positive diagonal entries $n_+,$ the number of negative diagonal entries $n_-,$ then the number of zero diagonal entries $n_0.$ As these make up the entire diagonal we have
$$ n_+ + n_0 + n_- = n $$

If all three, $ n_,  n_0 , n_-,$ are nonzero, I would probably say that the form is indefinite but add that it is "degenerate," by which I mean the rank is less than $n,$ the determinant is nonzero and so on.

Comment: Thanks Will! Do you think my definition above in the comment is correct?

Comment: @larrybr, why do you want a definition?

Comment: Hmm, your opening paragraph is a bit inaccurate. "The others" (those real symmetric matrices with zero determinants) can be indefinite unless $n\le2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

By the way, check out Wolfram's definition of Indefinite Matrix

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndefiniteMatrix.html

Comment: This is not correct. See my comment above.

Comment: You're right Santiago. Then any given square matrix has exactly one of the following labels: positive definite, negative definite, indefinite, the zero matrix.

Comment: No, the matrix given in Will Jagy's answer is none of those. You're missing the "semidefinite" possibilities.